# Readjusting responsive bootstrap rows and column

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, grid

Please how can i make centralized these 3 buttons and the last button be centralized on the next line without affecting the whole framework.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 col-lg-3 center-search">
                             <div class="">
                                 <button (click)="searchEmployeeName()" class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-success btn-sm">
                                     {{'Search' | translate}}
                                 </button>
                           </div>                       
                           <div class="">
                                <button (click)="reset()" class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-warning btn-sm ml-1">
                                   {{'Reset' | translate}}
                                </button>
                             </div>             
                             <div class="">
                                <button (click)="viewAll()"  class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-info btn-sm ml-1">
                                    {{'View All' | translate}}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <button (click)="exportToExcel()" class="btn btn-raised mr-1 pull-rightshadow-z-2 btn-danger btn-sm ml-1">
                                   {{'Export To Excel' | translate}}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                         </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add another div:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 col-lg-3 center-search">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="">
        <button (click)="searchEmployeeName()" class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-success btn-sm">
            {{'Search' | translate}}
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <button (click)="reset()" class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-warning btn-sm ml-1">
            {{'Reset' | translate}}
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <button (click)="viewAll()" class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-info btn-sm ml-1">
            {{'View All' | translate}}
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <button (click)="exportToExcel()" class="btn btn-raised mr-1 pull-rightshadow-z-2 btn-danger btn-sm ml-1">
            {{'Export To Excel' | translate}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didnt solve it, I want to place the first three buttons at the center of the page and the last button also centralized on the next line

Comment: Change the class <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> to <div class="row">